# Print by categories from a json in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I need to print a list of products ordered by category that I'm receiving in a json with Angular.

The json I have is:

```
{
    "MAIN MENU ": [{
        "id_prod": "1",
        "name_prod": "Artisanal chicken nuggets with mustard sauce",
        "descrip_prod": null,
        "price": "22.00",
        "category": "1"
    }],
    "EXPRESS MENU ": [{
        "id_prod": "8",
        "name_prod": "Guacamole with nachos",
        "descrip_prod": null,
        "price": "22.00",
        "category": "2"
    }],
    "LUNCH": [{
        "id_prod": "7",
        "name_prod": "Gazpacho",
        "descrip_prod": null,
        "price": "2.50",
        "category": "3"
    }],
    "PLATTERS": [],
    "BIRTHDAYS": [],
    "COFFEE BREAKS": [{
        "id_prod": "2",
        "name_prod": "Fresh Orange juice",
        "descrip_prod": null,
        "price": "2.00",
        "category": "6"
    }, {
        "id_prod": "9",
        "name_prod": "Coffee",
        "descrip_prod": null,
        "price": "1.50",
        "category": "6"
    }],
    "ASSORTED MINI PASTRIES": [{
        "id_prod": "3",
        "name_prod": "Assorted mini pastries ",
        "descrip_prod": null,
        "price": "1.60",
        "category": "7"
    }],
    "DRINKS": [{
        "id_prod": "5",
        "name_prod": "Sparkling water 50 cl",
        "descrip_prod": null,
        "price": "2.50",
        "category": "8"
    }],
    "IBERICOS": [{
        "id_prod": "6",
        "name_prod": "Chorizo ib\u00e9rico ",
        "descrip_prod": null,
        "price": "12.00",
        "category": "9"
    }],
    "OTHER": [{
        "id_prod": "4",
        "name_prod": "Mini croissant with ham and cheese",
        "descrip_prod": null,
        "price": "1.20",
        "category": "10"
    }]
}
```

I need to print this data in my view with a headline with the category name (drinks, main menu...) followed by the list of products of that category.

This is an example HTML that I made before connecting with the database:

```
<div class="cateringColumn cateringColumn-Product">
                <div class="cateringTitle">
                    <p>Coffee Breaks</p>
                </div>
                <p>Coffee</p>
                <p>Tea</p>
                <p>Cola Cao</p>
                <p>Fresh Orange Juice</p>
                <div class="cateringTitle">
                    <p>Assorted Mini Pastries</p>
                </div>
                <p>Assorted mini pastries (2 units per person)</p>
                <p>Assorted mini pastries (5 units per person)</p>
                <div class="cateringTitle">
                    <p>Other</p>
                </div>
                <p>Mini croissant with ham and cheese</p>
                <p>Yoghourt</p>
                <p>Fruit (1 piece or portion)</p>
 </div>
 <div class="cateringColumn cateringColumn-Prize">
                <div class="cateringTitle"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
                <p>1.50€</p>
                <p>1.50€</p>
                <p>1.50€</p>
                <p>2.00€</p>
                <div class="cateringTitle"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
                <p>1.60€</p>
                <p>4.00€</p>
                <div class="cateringTitle"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
                <p>1.20€</p>
                <p>1.05€</p>
                <p>1.50€</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your json is stored in a variable named `data`, you would have to do something like this:

```
<div class="cateringColumn cateringColumn-Prize" ng-repeat="(key, item) in data">
       <div class="cateringTitle">
            <p>{{key}}</p>
        </div>
        <p ng-repeat="subItem in item">{{subItem.name_prod}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, this was it, just a small change because the first div won't be printing for every category, but I created a div inside the .cateringColumn-Product and Price and placed there the ng-repeat. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-repeat and orderBy filter. **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/5MWKhYC9dQSNLvAi3XrD?p=preview)**

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    Menu Items
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="menu in items['MAIN MENU '] | orderBy: menu.category">
          <td>{{ menu.id_prod }}</td>
          <td>{{ menu.name_prod }}</td>
          <td>{{ menu.descrip_prod }}</td>
          <td>{{ menu.price }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```